# What happens when you use "new" twice on the same object?

Tags: c++

Lets say we have this..

```
class MyClass
{
    int value;

    void addIntToObject(int num)
    {
        value = num;
    }

}


MyClass *object = new MyClass();
object->addIntToObject(1);
object->addIntToObject(2);
```

Now let's say we do this again...

```
object = new MyClass();
```

By using new twice on the same object, does that mean we have deleted all data that was stored in object? can someone explain to me the exact workings of using new twice on the same object

Would this be an efficient way to free memory? (like using delete and delete[])

Comment: Do not use `new` and `delete` and raw pointers at all. YAGNI.

Comment: Not a duplicate, like, at all. Related advice does not replace an answer. Just like "Is wearing roller skates on a ladder considered good practice" is not a duplicate of "Why are stairs considered safer than ladders"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You didn't "do new twice on the same object".  The `new` expression creates an object.  By doing `new` twice you made two entirely separate objects.

The variable `object` is a *pointer*.  It points to other objects.  The `=` operator on a pointer means to change which object the pointer is pointing to.

So in your code there are two objects,  and you change `object` (the pointer) to point to the second object.  The first object still exists but nobody knows where it is, this is known as a *memory leak*.

Answer (score 0):

The thing on left side of = is a pointer i.e to be simple it can contain adrress of some memory location/object instance

When you do new MyClass() -> each execution of this statement will produce a new instance/object/memory of MyClass

So when you do this first time,

```
MyClass *object1 = new MyClass(); 
// here object1 now holds the address of object
created by executing 'new MyClass()' suppose that address is 1
```

Now create a object again,

```
object1 = new MyClass(); 
//here object1 now holds the address of object
created by again executing 'new MyClass()' suppose that address is 2
```

In the end both objects remain in memory i.e 1 as well 2. So nothing is deleted.

The pointer(left side of =) was first pointing to object with adrress 1. Now, it pointing to object with adress 2.